# Display images randomly on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I need help to code this using Javascript and HTML5. Please advise!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function Add() {
        if (document.getElementById('amount').value < 100){
            document.getElementById('amount').value++;
            newIMG = document.createElement("IMG");
            newIMG.src = 'jef-frog.gif';
            newIMG.width = 50;
            newIMG.height = 50;
            document.getElementById("imagedest").appendChild(newIMG);
        }
    }

    function Remove() {
        if(document.getElementById('amount').value > 0)
            document.getElementById('amount').value--;
        imagedest.removeChild(imagedest.lastChild);
    }

    function numeralsOnly(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
        var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : 
            ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H2>TESTING</H2>
    PREY
    <BR/>
    <img src="jef-frog.gif" alt="frogsonice.com" width="100" height="100"/>

<BR/>
<FORM>
    <INPUT type="button" value="+" onClick="Add()"> 
    <input type="text" id="amount" value=0  maxlength="3" size="1" onkeypress="return numeralsOnly(event)">
    <INPUT type="button" value="-" onClick="Remove()">

    <div id='imagedest'>
    </div>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tested the code, it will display in a `<div>` tag but I want to make it to appear in a canvas created above. I have no idea how to capture the thing in canvas. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the canvas api to draw something on it

- get the canvas (var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); )
- get the 2D context(var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");)
- draw the image (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)

**Example with a shape**

```
<html>  
 <head>  
  <script type="application/javascript">  
    function draw() {  
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
      if (canvas.getContext) {  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
      }  
    }  
  </script>  
 </head>  
 <body onload="draw();">  
   <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: 'code'
function Remove() {
if(document.getElementById('amount').value > 0)
document.getElementById('amount').value--;
imagedest.removeChild(imagedest.lastChild);
c5_context.drawImage(bgImage, destX, destY, 600, 300);
//c5_context.drawImage(frog, x, y, 58, 100).value--;
}
function numeralsOnly(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : 
((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
   }
    return true;
}
'code'

Comment: I think, I don't understand your problem :-(